# Как запустить модуль путем создания 2 файла в Паскале?

Tags: pascal

> Составить библиотеку алгоритмов для обработки произвольных числовых
> матриц (тип real):
>
> - определить строку с наибольшим (наименьшим) произведением положительных элементов
> - определить столбец с наибольшим (наименьшим) произведением положительных элементов
> - определить наибольший (наименьший) элемент в строке
> - определить наибольший (наименьший) элемент в столбце.

Как запустить модуль путем создания 2 файла? Где в сделанном ошибки?

```
unit lb12;
Interface
Const
m=10;
n=10;
Type
matr=array[1..n,1..m] of real;
Procedure wwod(C: matr; m,n: byte);
Function naimproizvstr(C:matr; m,n:integer):C;
Implementation
Procedure wwod(C: matr; m,n: integer;);
Var i,j: integer;
Begin
randomize;
For i:= 1 to n do
     Begin
       For j:= 1 to m do
       begin
         C[i,j]:=random(10-(-10))-10;
         Write(C[i,j]:3);
       end;
        Writeln;
     end;
end;
{----------------------------------------}
Function naimproizvstr(C:matr; m,n:integer):C;
var i,j:integer;  p:longInt;
 P := 0;
  for j:=1 to M do
  begin
  if C[i,j}>0 then
  begin
  p := p * C[1,j];
  Min := p;
  iMin := 1;
  end;
  end;
  for i:=2 to N do
  begin
    p := 0;
    for k:=1 to M do
    p := p * C[i,j];
    if p < Min then
    begin
      Min := p;
      iMin := i;
    end;
    end;
    Writeln('Произведение строки ',iMin,'равно ',Min);
    Readln;
end;
{---------------------------------------------}
Function naimproizvstr(C:matr; m,n:integer):C;
var i,j:integer;  p:longInt;
 P := 0;
  for j:=1 to M do
  begin
  if C[i,j}>0 then
  begin
  p := p * C[1,j];
  Max := p;
  iMax := 1;
  end;
  end;
  for i:=2 to N do
  begin
    p := 0;
    for k:=1 to M do
    p := p * C[i,j];
    if p > Max then
    begin
      Max := p;
      iMax := i;
    end;
    end;
    Writeln('Произведение строки ',iMax,'равно ',Max);
    Readln;
end;
{----------------------------------------}
Function naimel(C:matr; m,n:integer):C;
var i,j:integer;
For j:=1 to m do
begin
max:=a[1,j];
For i:=1 to n do
If max< a[i,j] then
max:=a[i,j];
Writeln('наибольший элемент ',j,'столбца ', max);
End;
Readln;
End.
```

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, так как ответ на него вряд ли может быть полезен кому-либо помимо автора вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот, поправил Ваш модуль - нашёл много косяков, обошёлся 2-мя процедурами (кроме процедуры ввода), если очень нужно, можно будет разбить и на 4 процедуры.

```
unit lb12;

Interface

Const
  m=10;
  n=10;

Type
 matr=array[0..n-1,0..m-1] of real;

Procedure wwod(C: matr; m,n: integer; Var F: Matr);
Procedure proizvstr(C:matr; m,n:integer; Flag: Boolean);
Procedure FindElem(C:matr; m,n:integer; Flag: Boolean);

Implementation

Procedure wwod(C: matr; m,n: integer; Var F: Matr);
Var
  i,j: integer;
Begin
  randomize;

  For i:= 0 to n-1 do
     Begin
       For j:= 0 to m-1 do
          begin
            C[i,j]:=random(20)-10;
            Write(C[i,j]:3);
          end;
        Writeln;
     end; 
  F:=C;
end;

{----------------------------------------}

Procedure proizvstr(C:matr; m,n:integer; Flag: Boolean);
var 
  i,j, Ind:integer;
  PrMas: Array[0..10] Of Real;
Begin

  for i:=0 to N-1 do
    begin
      PrMas[i]:=0;
      For j:=0 To M-1 Do
        if (C[i,j]>0) then
          Begin
            If (PrMas[i]=0) Then 
              PrMas[i]:=1;
            PrMas[i]:=PrMas[i]*C[i, j];
          End;
    end;

  Ind:=0;
  While (PrMas[Ind]=0) Do
    Inc(Ind);

  If (Flag) Then
    for i:=0 to N-1 do
      If ((PrMas[Ind]<PrMas[j]) And (PrMas[j]>0)) Then
          Ind:=i
      Else
  Else
    for i:=0 to N-1 do
      If ((PrMas[Ind]>PrMas[j]) And (PrMas[j]>0)) Then
          Ind:=i;

  Writeln('Произведение строки ',Ind+1,'равно ',PrMas[Ind]);
  Readln;
end;

Procedure FindElem(C:matr; m,n:integer; Flag: Boolean);
var 
  i,j, MinInd, MaxInd:integer;
  Min, Max: Real;
Begin
  Min:=C[0, 0];
  Max:=C[0, 0];

  If (Flag) Then
    For j:=0 to m-1 do
      For i:=0 to n-1 do
        If (max<C[i,j]) then
          Begin
            max:=C[i,j];
            MaxInd:=j;
          End
        Else
  Else
    For j:=0 to m-1 do
      For i:=0 to n-1 do
        If (min>C[i,j]) then
          Begin
            min:=C[i,j];
            MinInd:=j;
          End;

  If (Flag) Then
    Writeln('наибольший элемент ',max,' столбца ', MaxInd+1)
  Else
    Writeln('наименьший элемент ',min,' столбца ', MinInd+1);
  Readln;
End;

End.
```

А вот прога для теста этого модуля:

```
Program TestUnit;

Uses
  lb12;

Const
  M=10;
  N=10;

Var
  A: Matr;

Begin

  Wwod(A, 3, 3, A);

  ProizvStr(A, 3, 3, true);
  ProizvStr(A, 3, 3, false);

  FindElem(A, 3, 3, True);
  FindElem(A, 3, 3, False);

  ReadLn;
End.
```

Я уже третий раз призываю Вас форматировать код, так, ведь и самому легче разобраться! И ещё, рекомендую нумеровать массивы с нуля, если в Ваших планах есть переход на какой-нибудь Си-подобный язык, то лучше привыкать заранее, т. к. в Си и Си++ элементы массивов нумеруются с нуля (да и сам компилятор их нумерует с нуля).